# why int type value is not boxed as Integer

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
static void test(Integer x) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
}

static void test(long x) {
    System.out.println("long");
}

static void test(Byte x) {
    System.out.println("byte");
}

static void test(Short x) {
    System.out.println("short");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 5;
    test(i);
}
}
```

The output value is "long".

Can only tells me why it is not "Integer" since in Java, int value should be auto-boxed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the compiler has a choice of widening an `int` to a `long` or boxing an `int` as an `Integer`, it chooses the cheapest conversion: widening to a `long`. The rules for conversion in the context of method invocation are described in [section 5.3 of the Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) and the rules for selecting the matching method when there are several potential matches are described in [section 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) (specifically [section 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), but be warned that this is very dense reading).

Answer (score 0):

These are accepting only the instance of `integer` class for your test method which is not a primitive integer type of java. `Integer` is a class of java not the primitive type `int` like `String` class. On the other hand `long` is a primitive type and it has a subset of `int` so it chose that parameter as it is a closest match. You can try using double parameter as well. When int or long is signature is absence in a method parameter it chose to use the `double`'s one as it is the closest match.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 5;
    test(i);

    Integer smartInt= new Integer(5);
    test(smartInt); 
}
```